# Item views are not measured correctly when recycled in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have a scenario where, when views are recycled, the layout is incorrect. My row item layouts are as follows (note the `wrap_content` LinearLayout width, `weight`, and `ellipsize`):

```
     <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/header"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"               
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Ann really freaking long last name Droid"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
      </LinearLayout>
```

#### Desired behavior

```
    row1 | 1-short-text | 2-text | 3-more-text
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row2 | 1-short-text | 2-text | 3-more-text
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row3 | 1-long-ellipsiz...text | 2-text | 3-more-text
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row4 | 1-tiny | 2-text-longer | 3-more-text-blah
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

#### Actual behavior

```
    row1 | 1-...et | 2-text | 3-more-text     <-- ellipsized unnecessarily
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row4 | 1-short-text | 2-text | 3-more-text
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row2 | 1-long-ellipsiz...text | 2-text | 3-more-text
    ----------------------------------------------------
    row3 | 1-tiny |    2-text-longer | 3-more-text-blah  <-- spacing
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

What's the best way to go about solving this layout issue? Note: it works fine in a 4.1.1 emulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a known issue where TextViews don't re-measure in this scenario. I was able to solve this by doing the following when setting the data in my ViewHolder:

```
text1.setText("some-dynamic-text");
text1.requestLayout();  // <-- This is key... requestLayout after setting text.
```

When the view is recycled and new text was set, it wasn't laying out properly. Explicitly asking it to re-layout seems to re-calculate properly.

Comment: Could provide more info about the issue? Where did you read about it or something?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that seems to work is wrapping your troubling `TextView` in a `FrameLayout`.

```
...
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
...
```